# How do I override soft deletes within laravel

Tags: laravel

For my seeders I want to be able to truncate my tables, unfortunately there are some bound by foreign keys and additionally there are some that have soft deletes enabled.

To get around the inability to truncate a table based on soft deletes I am simply saying foreach Model::all() delete that model.. Maybe there is a better way? However for the tables that have soft deletes it isn't actually removing the record. How do I get around soft deletes when I really want to delete the record?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need `forceDelete` method

```
Model::where('condition')->where('may be other condition')->forceDelete();
```

or on particular model instance:

```
$modelInstance = Model::find($id);
$modelInstance->forceDelete();
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a statement to disable foreign check and model guard on your `DatabaseSeeder.php`:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Model::unguard();

        // Disable foreign key check for this connection before running seeders
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

        $this->call(UserTableSeeder::class);

        // Enable foreign check after seeding.
        DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');

        Model::reguard();
    }
}
```

and to force delete a soft-deletes model use `$model->forceDelete()` instead of `$model->delete()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I usually do:

In my migration file,

```
public function run() {
  DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
  DB::table('users')->truncate();

  // Create the table structure

  DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');

  }
```

This is basically force drop table ignoring the foreign key constraints.